# Library in the GAC used by multiple applications, does it share the same objects or not?

Tags: c#, ipc, gac

I have seen this in multiple questions, but so many of the accepted answers are contradictory.

Some say that only IPC can be used if you want to use a single instance (actually just a synced instance) of an object across applications and domains.

Others say that using a singleton pattern in an assembly in GAC will result in the data being shared because the GAC will share an instance if the DLL is already loaded by another assembly (providing the lib has a singleton pattern).

Somebody help me out and put this to rest, I need to share a Global object across multiple applications in multiple threads and need to know before I get too far into it if its even possible without IPC such as WCF. I would prefer to use the GAC as my library is more like a framework anyway that will be used by a suite of applications both developed by me and other 3rd party developers. Additionally speed is a major concern and serializing/deserializing an object to constantly sync it would probably add too much latency, would much rather it be a single instance referenced from multiple locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, each instance of an application is using it's own memory for all loaded assemblies. It is even possible to separate two singleton instances within one application *(by using [AppDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains))*

A singleton pattern can be used cross assembly, but this will always be within one AppDomain.

So two application doesn't share memory/object instances.

This is desired behavior, because you don't want other applications to access your Thread/Dispatcher/AppDomain(and load a custom assembly in your application)/Application class instances

---

If you need to 'share' memory or objects between applications, you'll need to serialize the data and 'transport' them over something like a communication layer.

For example:

- TCP/IP
- 'Shared' memory (named pipes)
- Files

Comment: So follow up question, keeping a rapidly changing set of data (hundreds of changes a second) synced between applications with minimal to no latency, what is the best method? They all seem to involve some sort of serialization/deserialization which would have its own latency.

Comment: _"hundreds of changes a second"_ If the data is volatile, you should only send a few. Mostly for volatile data UDP is used. (like locations within a game). If the data isn't volatile, you probably don't need "hundreds of changes a second". Can you 'predict' the next value? (like a moving object)

Comment: its has to do with hardware input so the volatility is necessary as the data source is volatile.

Comment: Alternatively, if I were to write a way using mutex and named pipes for any application that launches referencing an assembly to close and re-launch under my main libraries thread, would this be considered the same app domain thus shared?

Comment: Reading up on COM objects, this may be the way to go as it suggests direct access to objects, which I assume means no serialization/deserialization thus the fastest of my options.

Comment: I don't think using comobjects wil solve the cross application memory access. I think objects wil be still serialized beneath the hood. (not a com-object fan)

Comment: ugh, would think there would be a easier way for two applications referencing the same library to pass an object by way of a <typed> memory pointer or something

Comment: I'm not worried about the speed, both applications residing on the same machine I assume it will have thousands of iterations a second easy, i'm more worried about the latency that serialization/deserialization add on, any more than 1 ms or maybe even 2 is unacceptable.

Comment: I don't know any details but does the data change very much? Is it possible to 'send' only changes to other applications?

Comment: in most cases yes it does change rather rapidly, as much as a few hundred iterations a second.